# Remove period between Appendix letter and figure number in Appendix captions

Tags: captions, numbering, appendices, document-configuration

In the `report` class, figure captions appear as **Figure A.1**. I'm trying to get `LaTeX` to output **Figure A1** instead (i.e., remove the period between the letter and the number).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you run

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter\arabic{figure}}
```

after executing `\appendix`. Of course, if this numbering style should apply to `figure` captions everywhere in the document rather than just in the appendix (likely a rather poor idea, but...), be sure to run `\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter\arabic{figure}}` in the preamble.

---

A full test document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter\arabic{figure}}

\stepcounter{chapter} % increment the 'chapter' counter (to '1')
\begin{figure}[h] \caption{Hello} \label{fig:hello} \end{figure}
A cross-reference to figure \ref{fig:hello}.
\end{document}
```